# como actualizar Adoquery AfterDelete

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-2010

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
Select A.*, B.GroupName as PanelName 
From ehrPatientTestOrders A Left Outer Join VW_ehrTestPanels B On 
Coalesce(A.PanelCode, '') = B.Code 
Where A.PatientCode = '1800244'
```

Y Cuando hago:

```
adoquery1.UpdateBatch;
```

Me da el siguiente error:
Informacion de columna la clave insuficiente para realizar operacion Update o Refresh

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente es porque estás intentando hacer un UPDATE sobre lo que se conoce como una **"Consulta no-actualizable"**.

Cuando hacemos un `SELECT` sobre una tabla y cambiamos campos, el SGBD sabe de forma fácil qué campos has cambiado y cuales tiene que actualizar.

Cuando realizas un `SELECT` sobre **varias tablas** y modificas algunos campos, el problema es que el Gestor de Base de Datos ya no tiene tan claro qué campos debe actualizar y sobre qué tablas.

Sería posible que hubieras cambiado datos de varias tablas y con la consulta no tuviera los  datos suficientes para actualizarlas todas (por ejemplo, si no posee los valores de las claves primarias). En esos casos devuelve un error similar al que has obtenido.

Algunos SGND's son más "listos" que otros en estos casos, pero hay algunas situaciones en que no tienen solución.

Si usas un `INNER JOIN` estás obteniendo registros 1 a 1 de dos tablas. En tu caso estás utilizando un `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, por lo tanto puedes obtener registros de la tabla A, que no tienen correspondencia en la tabla B. Esa situación puede provocará el error comentado.